# What does the environment variable IGNORE_NORMALISATION_GIT_HEAD_MOVE do?

Tags: c#, git, environment-variables, gitversion, git-detached-head

I have a C# code base that uses GitVersion.MsBuild. Sometimes my Jenkins build server gives me this error:

```
GitVersion.BugException: GitVersion has a bug, your HEAD has moved after repo normalisation.
To disable this error set an environmental variable called IGNORE_NORMALISATION_GIT_HEAD_MOVE to 1
```

This often happens when building a feature branch that is not based on the latest master (i.e., master has moved since the feature branch was made).

The error message describes a suggested fix/workaround, but I am hesitant to do this because I don't know what environmental variable IGNORE_NORMALISATION_GIT_HEAD_MOVE *does*, and I cannot find a description of it anywhere.

If I set IGNORE_NORMALISATION_GIT_HEAD_MOVE to 1, what side effects does this have?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I asked the same question in [an issue on GitVersion's GitHub](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2934).

Comment: It doesn't do anything in Git. It might do something in gitversion.

Comment: That env var isn't recognized by any the standard Git tool. I googled it and got a handful of helpful answers such as https://ajmburns.wordpress.com/2019/02/09/gitversion-and-teamcity-configuring-gitversion-for-githubflow/. I've been using Git for many years and have never heard of GitVersion. Since it seems to be pretty obscure and it's causing you problems you might want to consider whether you should continue using it.

Comment: @KurtisRader It's popular enough to get its own tag here! That env var just silences the warning, [see here](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/661c8c8d33786e584c5399bf38ef423e5e6cb1a2/src/GitVersion.Core/Core/GitPreparer.cs#L269). You'll need to read a bit further to understand the consequences of ignoring the warning however. There are a number of [issues which reference that env var](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/search?q=IGNORE_NORMALISATION_GIT_HEAD_MOVE&type=issues): maybe they're worth a read? If they don't help, maybe open your own? The error message asks you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the maintainers of GitVersion, this variable just suppresses a **BugException** that otherwise gets throw in this situation.

See issue here: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2934